# Upload Python requests GZipped body as is to S3 but only after content fully received

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to upload an API request GZipped response as-is to AWS S3 bucket and let Snowflake Snowpipe further upload it to the Snowflake database. I thought it would be a good idea to not to uncompress the result before uploading it because it is unnecessary.

I'm using Python code like this:

```
with requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, stream=True) as response:

    if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        response.raise_for_status()

    s3_client = BOTO3_SESSION.client('s3')
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=response.raw, Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
```

This works like a charm for most of the time, but occasionally a file is not uploaded by Snowpipe although there are no issues with the uploaded file. What I'm suspecting is that an SNS notification is sent before the file is completely uploaded. In one case the latest write timestamp of the S3 file is seven seconds later than the PIPE_RECEIVED_TIME informed by Snowflake function `information_schema.copy_history`.

I think that Snowpipe tries to upload a file that is not completely written to S3 and will not upload it again once the file is completed by design because files are uploaded by Snowpipe only once they're created for the first time.

Is there a way to ensure the response is fully retrieved before uploading it to S3 without uncompressing the response body?

Comment: `s3_client.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=io.BytesIO(response.raw.read()), ...)` should do it. FWIW, this behavior seems like a bug on the part of something - maybe snowpipe? I'm mot familiar enough with it to say, but intuitively I would have expected your code to work just fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out! This fails very occasionally so I can't promptly confirm this actually solves the problem, but I'll get back to this sooner or later. (Reminder set for 2020-11-01)

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you that this didn't prevent Snowpipe upload failure from occurring this morning again. Probably my assumption about the cause was wrong.

Comment: Now the problem was found. We were writing a file to S3 with the exactly same file name for more than once. That is not supported by Snowpipe. But I recreated the empty result check using @AdamKG suggestion, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Answering for completeness (curating the tags):

File were being written to S3 with the exactly same file name multiple times. The issue was resolved by the hint from @AdamKG:

```
s3_client.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=io.BytesIO(response.raw.read()), ...)
```